# Comparar Data angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Gostaria de comparar duas datas no angular js, as duas datas estão assim:

```
Sat Oct 14 2017 11:43:46 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
Sat Oct 14 2017 17:53:51 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

Como consigo comprar essas duas datas?

Answer (score 1):

A comparação de datas pode ser feita utilizando JavaScript puro através de objetos da classe Date.

```
const data1 = new Date('Sat Oct 14 2017 11:43:46 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)');
const data2 = new Date('Sat Oct 14 2017 17:53:51 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)');

const datasIguais = data1.getTime() === data2.getTime();  -- false
const datasDiferentes = data1.getTime() !== data2.getTime(); -- true
const primeiraDataAnteriorSegunda = data1.getTime() < data2.getTime(); -- true
const primeiraDataPosteriorSegunda = data1.getTime() > data2.getTime(); -- false
```

Observe que você deve sempre fazer a comparação a partir do retorno do método getTime() da classe Date que retorna o valor de tempo que é o número de milissegundos desde 1 de Janeiro de 1970 (UTC). **Não faça comparações diretamente entre as variáveis**, pois são apenas referências para os objetos instanciados.